# How to get last word inside slashes using Regular Expressions

Tags: regex

How to get last word inside slashes using Regular Expressions in a URL?

Example : http://aaa/bbb/ccc/ddd.aspx returns ccc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using lookbehind and lookahead, this should work

```
(?<=/)[^/]+(?=/[^/]*$)
```

`(?<=/)`  the match must be preceeded by `/`

`[^/]+` this will capture everything except a `/` - as many as possible.

`(?=/[^/]*$)` the match must be followed by a `/`, any number of non-slashes, and the end of string.

Answer (score 5):

Something like this

`/([^/]+)/[^/]*$`

Should match the last section of your URL and store `ccc` in a group.